# Powershell - Insert variable into another variable

Tags: regex, powershell

Using `sc sdshow <servicename>` I can query the current ACL for that service.  For instance:

`D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;RPWPCR;;;S-1-5-21-1188791649-1212328039-3264839704-1028)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)`

I set the return above to be the variable $acl.  Using a different script, I can query for a users sid, then create a new ACE, set to the variable $ace:

`(A;;RPWPCR;;;S-1-5-21-1188791649-1212328039-3264839704-1027)`

However, what I know need to do is insert this new ACE into the ACL, right after the D: at the very beginning, and I need to do this via Powershell.  I know it is easy to add it at the beginning or end of the string, but I am unable to figure out how to add it right after the D:

Comment: Why do it this way when `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` exist?

Comment: That would work for file/folder acl's, but I don't think that works for services.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there is a correct way to do what you're trying to do but to answer your question, you can use the following replacement pattern to insert `$ace` right after `D:`:

```
$acl = 'D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWP....'
$ace = '(A;;RPWPCR;;;S-1-5-21-1188791649-1212328039-3264839704-1027)'
$acl -creplace '(?<=^D:)', $ace
```

Don't even need regex for this, you can use `.Insert` method:

```
$acl.Insert(2, $ace)
```